# Simple C/C++ network I/O library

Tags: c++, c, sockets, timeout, pthreads

I have the following problem to solve.  I want to make a number of requests to a number of "remote" servers (actually, a server farm we control).  The connection is very simple.  Send a line, and then read lines back.  Because of the number of requests and the number of servers, I use pthreads, one for each request.

The naive approach, using blocking sockets, does not work; very occasionally, I'll have a thread stuck in 'connect'.  I cannot use SIGALRM because I am using pthreads.  I tried converting the code to O_NONBLOCK but this vastly complicated the code to read single lines.

What are my options?  I'm looking for the simplest solution that allows the following pseudocode:

```
// Inside a pthread
try {
    req = connect(host, port);
    req.writeln("request command");
    while (line = req.readline()) {
        // Process line
    }
} catch TimeoutError {
    // Bitch and complain
}
```

My code is in C++ and I'm using Boost.  A quick look at [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html) shows me that it probably isn't the correct approach, but I could be wrong.  [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) is far, far too heavy-weight to solve this problem.

Comment: Why is Boost ASIO the wrong approach? I agree about ACE (and unless it's been updated to use modern C++ idioms, I'd rather avoid it on that basis as well!).

Comment: I think Boost ASIO is the wrong approach because it does not seem to support timeouts on connect or read/write.  Am I mistaken?  The standard approach seems to be to use SIGALRM which seems inappropriate given my extensive use of pthreads.

Comment: The question of one thread per socket aside, what's wrong with pthread-kill()?

Comment: Duck, that's a good question.  You are suggesting that my main thread uses a timer when doing a pthread_join and if the timer expires, kill any remaining threads?  That might work.  Also, you seem to be suggesting not using one thread per socket.  Do you think Boost asio would make it easy for me to create, say, ten sockets and then asynchronously read from each without bothering with threads?

Comment: Not so much kill them but send a sigusr to get them out of the blocking connect and let the signal handler set a switch so when they return they clean themselves up.  I haven't used boost asio so I can't comment on that directly but if you have a lot of connections to handle the underlying paradigm is the direction you should think about moving in IMO.

Comment: ASIO can be used with timers. You define a dead line timer, the operation and wait on both. Check the tutorials, there is a timer example and a basic echo client/server that you can fit together.

Comment: Okay, lots of people seem to think that the boost asio timeouts won't be affected by running inside a pthread.  I'll take a look in more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the comments and i think you can use boost::asio with boost::asio::deadline_timer

Fragment of a code:

```
    void restart_timer()
    {
       timer_.cancel();
       timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
       timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&handleTimeout,
       MyClass::shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
```

Where handleTimeout is a callback function, `timer_` is boost::asio::deadline_timer 
and MyClass is similar to

```
    class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
    {
     public:

     shared_ptr<Y> f()
     {
       return shared_from_this();
     }
    }
```

You can call restart_timer before connect ou read/write

More [information](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) about `share_from_this()`

Comment: I spent some time converting my code over to boost asio and it does indeed appear to work well.  Asynchronous socket i/o and deadline timers seemed to do what I need, and my code is now seemingly stable.  Took a bit of rewriting behind the scenes but the rest of my code is almost unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at libevent?

http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/

It's totally different paradigm but the performance is so amazing.

memcached is built on top of libevent.

Comment: libevent is a good idea, I'm going to read up on that now to see if it better fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this happens 'very occasionally'. Your 'connect' side should have the fault tolerance and error handling you are looking for but you should also consider the stability of your servers, DNS, network connections, etc.

The underlying protocols are very sturdy and work very well, so if you are experiencing these kind of problems that often then it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able close the socket from the other thread. That should cause the connect to fail.